# outputText using a function with param

Tags: apex, visualforce, outputtext, repeat, apex-param

So I am trying to iterate through a list of custom objects and print out the information that I need. The issue is that with this object I cannot guarantee where the information I need is so I made a method in my controller that given the object, it will return a string with the information that I want to print. My problem is trying to combine the repeat, outputText and param components.

Here is the visualforce chunk that I have:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relationships}" var="relation">
    <apex:outputText value="{!getOutput}">
        <apex:param value="relation" assignTo="{!relationshipToPrint}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

and here are the snippits of my apex controller code that are relevant:

```
public List<Relationship_Detail__c> relationships { get; set; }
public Id recordID { get;set; }
public Relationship_Detail__c relationshipToPrint { get;set; }

public String getOutput(){
    String result = '';
    boolean isPrimary = (relationshipToPrint.First_Contact__c == recordID
            || relationshipToPrint.First_Account__c == recordID);
    if(isPrimary){
        if(relationshipToPrint.Second_Contact__c != null){
            result = relationshipToPrint.Second_Contact__r.Name;
        }
        else{
            result = relationshipToPrint.Second_Account__r.Name;
        }
        result = result + ' (' + relationshipToPrint.Second_Relationship_Type__r.Name + ')';
    }
    else{
        if(relationshipToPrint.First_Contact__c != null){
            result = relationshipToPrint.First_Contact__r.Name;
        }
        else{
            result = relationshipToPrint.First_Account__r.Name;
        }
        result = result + ' (' + relationshipToPrint.First_Relationship_Type__r.Name + ')';
    }
    return result;
}
```

The function works correctly, however, I am having difficulty passing the current custom object into the relationshipToPrint variable so that it can be used in the method. I hope that this makes some sense and please feel free to ask questions.

Comment: The usual solution to this is to use a wrapper class. But your solution may work if you change `value="relation"` to `value="{!relation}"` so that you are reference the loop `var`. Also `value="{!getOutput}"` should probably be `value="{!output}"` as the "get" part of the name is implied.

Comment: No that doesn't change my output @KeithC. I ran an assert to make sure that relationshipToPrint was not null when I use it in getOutput and it didn't pass. So the param is not setting it before the outputText calls the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper approach - the normal solution to providing derived values in a table row - would be to return a list of this inner class:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private MyController c;
    public Relationship_Detail__c sob {get; private set;}
    Wrapper(MyController c, Relationship_Detail__c sob) {
        this.c = c;
        this.sob = sob;
    }
    public String output {
        get {
            Boolean isPrimary = sob.First_Contact__c == c.recordID
                    || sob.First_Account__c == c.recordID;
            if (isPrimary) {
                return (sob.Second_Contact__c != null
                        ? sob.Second_Contact__r.Name
                        : sob.Second_Account__r.Name)
                        + ' (' + sob.Second_Relationship_Type__r.Name + ')';
            } else {
                return (sob.First_Contact__c != null
                        ? sob.First_Contact__r.Name
                        : sob.First_Account__r.Name)
                        + ' (' + sob.First_Relationship_Type__r.Name + ')';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

from the list property (wherever that is built):

```
public List<Wrapper> relationships { get; set; }
```

so that the Visualforce can just be this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relationships}" var="relation">
    <apex:outputText value="{!relation.output}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Looks very straight forward although when I am building the individual wrappers. What am I passing for the MyController? Do I pass it the extension controller and if so how do I do that within the extension?

Comment: Yes you need to change MyController to the class name of your extension and when you create the wrapper use `new Wrapper(this, sob)` - `this` will be your controller instance and `sob` should be one of the queried Relationship_Detail__c objects. Alternatively you could just pass in the recordID in the constructor.